# SQLite insert method writes unidentified values

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, cordova

I try to run this code after I loaded my database and when I check what's the inserted value it returns unidentified instead of the text.  With the 1st part I create the database and then I try to insert data to see if it works.

HTML:

```
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="text" id="firstName">
  <input type="text" id="lastName">
  <input type="text" id="stats">
  <input type="text" id="notes">

</div>
              <button id="insert">Insert</button>
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var myDB;
//Open Database Connection
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
function onDeviceReady(){
myDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "appDatabase.db", location: 'default'});
}
//Create new table
$("#createTable").click(function(){
    myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS leads3 (id integer primary key,firstName text,lastName text,notes text)', [],
        function(tx, result) {
            alert("Table created successfully");
        },
        function(error) {
              alert("Error occurred while creating the table.");
        });
    });
});

    $("#insert").click(function(){
      var firstName = "First Name";
      var lastName =$("#lastName").val();
      var stats =$("#stats").val();
      myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
            var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO leads3 (firstName,lastName,notes) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, [firstName,lastName,notes]
                , function(tx, result) {
                     alert('Inserted');
                },
                function(error){
                     alert('Error occurred');
                });
        });
    });
   });
```

Comment: Start by verifying that these variables actually contain what you think they do. (Since this is lacking context - what HTML does this apply to in the first place - we can hardly say anything more specific about this at this point. Provide a proper [mre] if you need more help debugging this.)

Comment: @04FS I put the HTML as well

Comment: So use the `console.log()` method or other preferred tracing technique to write out the values of the firstName, lastName and stats variables just before calling the `executeSql()`.  Also, what do you mean by "unidentified"?  Normally a database field is NULL or perhaps has an empty string when it has no data in it.  How are you checking contents of the database?